# opencv 3.0 HOG.cpp

Tags: gpu, opencv3.0

I am running `opencv 3.0's` sample code `hog.cpp` (from the folder `\samples\gpu\hog.cpp`) for people detection, using the GPU. (the CPU part crashes for me). The code compiles, but when I run it, it crashes at the line:

> gpu_hog->detectMultiScale(gpu_img, found);
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEDE717A28 (opencv_core300.dll) in
>   Hog3StandAlone.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x000002380000013C.

I am using `visual studio 2012`, `Windows 7 Pro 64 bit`.

Comment: Post library directory and dependencies. Also show us the string output by cv::getBuildInformation();

Comment: hi there, sorry for the response:    here's the build info

Comment: videoio: Removing WinRT API headers by default

General configuration for OpenCV 3.0.0 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Platform:
    Host:                        Windows 6.1 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.3.0
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 11 2012 Win64
    CMake build tool:            C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1700

Comment: C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 17.0.61030.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /wd4251 /wd4324 /MP12  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG  /Zi
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D

Comment: C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi    /MP12  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO  /debug
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL 
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32 vfw32 cudart nppc nppi npps cublas cufft
    3rdparty dependencies:       zlib libjpeg libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf ippicv

Comment: I need your library directory, something like <OPENCV_DIR>/build/.../lib, and additional dependencies, opencv_coreXXX.lib, etc... look in the project properties

Comment: OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 hal cudev core cudaarithm flann imgproc ml video cudabgsegm cudafilters cudaimgproc cudawarping imgcodecs photo shape videoio cudacodec highgui objdetect ts features2d calib3d cudafeatures2d cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo stitching superres videostab
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 python3 viz

  Windows RT support:            NO

Comment: GUI: 
    QT:                          NO
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
    WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.12)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    GDAL:                        NO

Comment: Video I/O:
    Video for Windows:           YES
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      codec:                     YES (ver 55.18.102)
      format:                    YES (ver 55.12.100)
      util:                      YES (ver 52.38.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 2.3.100)
      resample:                  NO
      gentoo-style:              YES

Comment: OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    OpenNI2:                     NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            NO
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Intel PerC:                  NO

Comment: Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     8.2.1 [8.2.1]
         at:                     E:/opencv300_release/sources/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_win
    Use IPP Async:               NO
    Use Eigen:                   NO
    Use TBB:                     NO
    Use OpenMP:                  NO
    Use GCD                      NO
    Use Concurrency              YES
    Use C=:                      NO
    Use pthreads for parallel for:
                                 NO

Comment: Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 7.0)
    Use OpenCL:                  YES

  NVIDIA CUDA
    Use CUFFT:                   YES
    Use CUBLAS:                  YES
    USE NVCUVID:                 NO
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             20 21 30 35 50
    NVIDIA PTX archs:            50
    Use fast math:               YES

  OpenCL:
    Version:                     dynamic
    Include path:                E:/opencv300_release/sources/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Use AMDFFT:                  NO
    Use AMDBLAS:                 NO

Comment: Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 NO

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 NO

  Python (for build):            NO

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:
    mex:                         C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2012b/bin/mex.bat
    Compiler/generator:          Not working (bindings will not be generated)

  Documentation:
    Doxygen:                     NO
    PlantUML:                    NO

Comment: Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       YES
    Performance tests:           YES
    C/C++ Examples:              NO

  Install path:                  E:/opencv300_r/install

  cvconfig.h is in:              E:/opencv300_r
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: ok ok... that's not what I'm asking.. :D see my previous comment

Comment: library directories: $(VCInstallDir)lib\amd64;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib\amd64;$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64);

Comment: additional library directories: C:\boost\stage\lib;C:\BayesLib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories);%opencv2411_x64_debug%\lib

Comment: here we go. You're linking to opencv 2.4.11, not opencv 3.0

Comment: additional dependencies: opencv_calib3d300.lib
opencv_core300.lib
opencv_cudaarithm300.lib
opencv_cudabgsegm300.lib
opencv_cudacodec300.lib
opencv_cudafeatures2d300.lib
opencv_cudafilters300.lib
opencv_cudaimgproc300.lib
opencv_cudalegacy300.lib
opencv_cudaobjdetect300.lib
opencv_cudaoptflow300.lib
opencv_cudastereo300.lib
opencv_cudawarping300.lib
opencv_cudev300.lib
opencv_features2d300.lib
opencv_flann300.lib
opencv_hal300.lib
opencv_highgui300.lib
opencv_imgcodecs300.lib
opencv_imgproc300.lib
opencv_ml300.lib
opencv_objdetect300.lib

Comment: opencv_photo300.lib
opencv_shape300.lib
opencv_stitching300.lib
opencv_superres300.lib
opencv_ts300.lib
opencv_video300.lib
opencv_videoio300.lib
opencv_videostab300.lib

Comment: opencv2411_x64_debug = C:\opencv30\x64

Comment: oh, it's a misnomer, opencv2411_x64_debug is actually C:\opencv30\x64 in the system variable.

Comment: ok.. but it should be: C:\opencv30\x64\vc11\lib

Comment: hi Miki, sorry, in the system variables, opencv2411_x64_debug actually points to C:\opencv30\x64, so that should be okay... so not sure what the problem is.  thanks.

Comment: you are missing the "vc11" in the middle..

Comment: hmm, i can't seem to find the vc11 part, the installed folder's path is: C:\opencv30\x64\  then, there are the \bin, \include, \lib, \share folders in there...

Comment: i will try reinstalling opencv 3.0 and see if that works. will keep this posted.  thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things that can cause such a problem.

[The code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/gpu/hog.cpp) itself seems "fine".

What I suggest is that you compile the program in **Debug** mode. Then, run it from Visual Studio. The IDE's debug session should stop at the exact place in which the "access violation" happened. From there, you can have a more precise idea on the origin of the problem.

For example, I got similar problem at [line #341](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/gpu/hog.cpp#L341)

```
vc >> frame;
```

because the `VideoCapture vc` object returned *corrupted* frames.

Your problem might be similar (or completely different. That's why you should run a debug session in Visual Studio)

Comment: thanks, it is running in debug mode currently, and it crashes at line 399 gpu_hog->detectMultiScale(gpu_img, found) for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the same sample before and worked without any problems as far as I remember. On the other hand, this access violation is probably due to the fact that your input "gpu_img" is empty or corrupted. Make it sure that you read the frames correctly (you can use imshow function to visually examine) and also you upload it into gpu_img as well. I don't see any other possible explanation.

Comment: yes, i commented out the detection code, and the images show up fine, so   it is not a problem with the gpu_img... thanks.